# GAE Python - libs on my requirements.txt are not installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using flexible environments and I'd like to know what am I doing wrong when deploying it.

This is my requirements.txt

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

If I uninstall this lib on my local computer this error will be thrown:

```
No module named MySQLdb
```

When I run "pip install -r requirements.txt" the lib will be installed  and I'll able to use MySQLdb with no problems.

The problem is, when I upload this to server  it does not install and the error  "No module named MySQLdb" is thrown on production...

From what I understood reading some docs, is that I'd only need to specify which libs I want to use and google would do the installing on production.

Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you need to call it MySQLdb? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: I also tried that, but didn't work. Btw i'm deploying with gcloud

Answer (score 0):

MySql-python doesn't install properly using PyPi/pip. At the time of this question, it required the user to install some other C library, so that's probably why GAE can't install it. However, there are other replacement packages that should provide the exact same functions/API and install using pip.

Another alternative is to install the package directly into your app in a `/lib` folder and make sure that the app can install MySql-python correctly, and avoid the requirements.txt installer completely.